# Writing to the register at the falling clock edge: Problem in the code

Tags: verilog, clock, cpu-registers, flip-flop

I wrote the Verilog code for a register file having 4 registers (each 32 bit).

**Expected Outcome** Write to the register file should take place at the falling edge of the clock. The clock passed to register file is *regClk* (gated clock). *Please ignore the fact that gated clocks create problems because this is for an assignment and I have to use this clock*

**Problem** As seen in the clock diagram, write to the *reg0* happens at t=10 (falling edge of *regClk[0]*). But after t=10, there is no falling edge, but still a write to *reg0* takes place at t=18. Similar pattern is followed all the way till *reg4*. Whenever, there is a falling edge for *reg_n*, the same value gets written to the *reg_n-1* even though there is no falling edge in its clock.

I am attaching the code and the clock diagram:

**DFF with asynchronous clear**

```
module dff(q,d,clk,reset);
    input d,clk,reset;
    output q;
    reg q;
    always @(negedge clk , posedge reset)
    begin
        if(reset)
            q<=1'b0;
        else
            q<=d;
    end
endmodule
```

**Register 32 bit**

```
module reg_32bit(q,d,clk,reset);
    input [31:0] d;
    input clk,reset;
    output [31:0] q;
    genvar j;
    generate for(j=0;j<32;j=j+1)
                begin: reg_loop
                dff flipflop (q[j],d[j],clk,reset);
                end
    endgenerate
endmodule
```

**Register File**

```
module regf(clk,reset,ReadReg1, ReadReg2, WriteData, WriteReg, RegWrite, ReadData1, ReadData2);
    input clk,reset,RegWrite;
    input [1:0] ReadReg1, ReadReg2, WriteReg;
    input [31:0] WriteData;
    output [31:0] ReadData1, ReadData2;

    wire [3:0] decOut;
    wire [3:0] regClk;
    dec_2to4 dec1(decOut,WriteReg);

    wire [31:0] RegFileAcc[0:3];

    assign regClk[0]=(decOut[0] & RegWrite & clk);
    assign regClk[1]=(decOut[1] & RegWrite & clk);
    assign regClk[2]=(decOut[2] & RegWrite & clk);
    assign regClk[3]=(decOut[3] & RegWrite & clk);

    reg_32bit regs1 (RegFileAcc[0],WriteData,regClk[0],reset);
    reg_32bit regs2 (RegFileAcc[1],WriteData,regClk[1],reset);
    reg_32bit regs3 (RegFileAcc[2],WriteData,regClk[2],reset);
    reg_32bit regs4 (RegFileAcc[3],WriteData,regClk[3],reset);

    bit32_mux4to1 mux1(ReadData1,{RegFileAcc[3], RegFileAcc[2], RegFileAcc[1], RegFileAcc[0]}, ReadReg1);
    bit32_mux4to1 mux2(ReadData2,{RegFileAcc[3], RegFileAcc[2], RegFileAcc[1], RegFileAcc[0]}, ReadReg2);
endmodule
```

[The clock diagram for this register file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3brw.jpg)

Comment: *ignore the fact that gated clocks create problems* -- what does it mean? if it has glitches, it can cause the behavior.

Comment: @Serge I think gates used in verilog don't lead to any delays until explicitly stated. So, is this problem really possible becuase of gated clocks? PS: Please excuse me if I am wrong here. I am quite new to verilog.

Comment: if the clock line contains glitches, they are not shown in a regular trace. These are the glitches inside a simulation tick. Nevertheless they produce edges which flops can react to. You can add `always @* $display ($time,clk)` to see if the clock changes when you do not expect it. There could be other drivers for regClk that can cause glitches as well. it is difficult to tell what is going on in your extracted code.